# Extract coordinate data from KML path

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, route, mapping

I have a route defined by a series of waypoints - how can i extract as many coordinates as possible from that route as possible?

I need to extract about 100-150 coordinates that lie along a route that I have defined by a series of steps. Is this possible?

It is a series of points. Basically a path (polyline) generated by google maps. I have been able to export a KML to load in google earth, but I am not sure of how to go about extracting the data.

Consider the following.

```
           START           END
Step 1:   (a1, b1)       (a2, b1)
Step 2:   (a2, b1)       (a2, b2)
Step 3:   (a2, b2)       (a3, b2)
Step 4:   (a3, b2)       (a3, b3)
```

I would like to get 10 coordinates that lie between step 1 START AND END, Step 2 START AND END, Step 3 START AND END, and Step 4 START AND END.

So this path would return an additional 40 points.

Comment: Is the route a line or is it a series of points? What program are you trying to do this in? Do you need specific locations along the route or just a string of points an even distance apart? Please edit your question to include these details if possible.

Comment: Just tried [this](http://www.landviser.net/content/extracting-geographical-lat-long-data-google-earth-kml-kmz-files-excel) and got a boat load of coordinates within Excel that would have to be massaged a little more to work with. Looks like it would probably work for you.

Comment: Do you want to interpolate new points between the existing waypoints??

Comment: @Mesa yes that would be good

Comment: There would be a relatively straightforward way using QGIS, but if you don't have any GIS knowledge, it would require sitting down and follow a few tutorials first.

Comment: this function can help you accomplish this easily in python: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Answer (score 0):

The following requires Excel (I haven't tried this with any other spreadsheet software, but kml is quite common and might be read in a similar fashion with other software). Also, my solution does not separate coordinates per part, but might serve as a start for you.

Open MS Excel, and add a new file that is your kml. Direct wizard to ensure Excel recognizes your file as a kml. Select the cells containing the coordinates, go to Data tab>Text to Columns and choose comma delimited.

My longitude values had 0 in front of them so I did a find and replace as shown below.

[image]

Also, my coordinates were separated by columns and not rows. So I used `=IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN(P2)),P2,"")` to separate my longitude values and  `=IF(ISODD(COLUMN(P2)),P2,"")` to separate my latitude values. Then I transposed these values to place them in rows.